# change owner ship of smart contract (upgradable)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I'm using openzeppelin to build an upgradable smart contract but when I deploy the contract the owner of the contract is transferring automatically to the admin proxy and I want to interact with the smart contract he says that I'm not the owner but when i look at the proxy admin I can see that I'm the owner but in the other contract the owner is proxy admin .
how can I change the owner of the contract ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: how are you deploying your contracts?

Comment: i'm deploying it with hardhat

Comment: can you show your deployment details?